# How to get the sendButton to show on Google Chrome when using FlyerChat?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-web

Currently using @FlyerHQ/React-Native-Chat-UI to build a chat UI experience for our AWS backend. We have most everything working, and most of my testing was done in expo. Ideally, this will be deployed as a react-native-web application first. Now that I am testing in google chrome on my android device, the send button no longer seems to appear.

https://github.com/flyerhq/react-native-chat-ui

We are just using the base chat implementation for now.

```
<Chat messages={messages} onSendPress={handleSendPress} user={user} />;
```

Has anyone used this package in a react-native-web application before? Has anyone else had a similar problem? Is there any other information I can provide that will help?